# Cant set up the Firestore emulator for testing Firestore security rules

Tags: npm, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-cli

Im trying to set up the firebase simulator for testing the security rules for my Firestore realtime DB.

Im following the official google tutorial at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

I have set up the Firebase CLI using the google official tutorial at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator
but when i run the command:

```
 firebase setup:emulators:firestore
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  MY_USER$ firebase setup:emulators:firestore
  Error: setup:emulators:firestore is not a Firebase command
```

Here are some info on what is installed on my machine, Im suspecting that the reason might be a old version of firebase but Im not sure since i have reinstalled everything connected to firebase locally:

```
MY_USER$ firebase -V
3.18.5

MY_USER$ npm show firebase
firebase@5.9.1 | Apache-2.0 | deps: 8 | versions: 700
Firebase JavaScript library for web and Node.js
https://firebase.google.com/

MY_USER$ npm show firebase-tools
firebase-tools@6.5.0 | MIT | deps: 39 | versions: 120
Command-Line Interface for Firebase
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

MY_USER$ npm -v -g firebase
6.7.0

MY_USER$ npm -v firebase-tools
6.7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The instance of firebase-tools that is in your path doesn't match the one that's being reported by npm.  The one in your path that you're showing with `firebase -V` is **really** old.  You're going to have to figure out what you actually have installed and where, and possibly change your PATH to match.  In the end, you need to be able to run `firebase -V` and see version 6.5.0, which is the latest public version at the time I'm writing this.